# Firebase: Show items only once for each user using RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

I'd like to have a `RecyclerView` showing random questions to the users. Once the question is answered (wright or wrong), it should never appear for this user again, even if he closes the app. After that, the activity is reloaded and a new random question appears.

When the users see all the questions in database, it should show a message saying that there is no more question at that time.

My code right now is putting in `Firebase` database if the user saw the the question after the click.

I tried to put an `if` statement (but it seems a stupid idea) and it's working for a short time. Basically it says, if the child exists, reload the activity. When database has thousands of questions it'll work for a period, but will crash one day.

My problems:

First, I don't want to reload the activity n times to "find" a question which hasn't appear yet.

Second, I can't determine when the users see all the questions to show a message.

Here is the code:

```
  mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Category").child(category_key).child("Questions");
query = mDatabase.orderByChild("randomId").startAt(randomValue).limitToFirst(1);

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Questions, QuestionViewHolder>
            firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Photos, QuestionViewHolder>(
            Question.class,
            R.layout.question_grid,
            QuestionViewHolder.class,
            query
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final QuestionViewHolder viewHolder, final Question model, int position) {

            final String question_key = getRef(position).getKey();
            final String category_key = getIntent().getExtras().getString("category_id");

            mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (dataSnapshot.child(question_key).child("ViwedBy").hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {

                        finish();
                        startActivity(getIntent());


                    } else {

                        viewHolder.setQuestion(model.getQuestion());{

                            @Override
                            public void onClick (View v){


                                mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                    mDatabaseTest = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Category").child(category_key).child("Questions").child(question_key).child("ViewedBy").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                                    mDatabaseTest.setValue(true);

                                     finish();
                                     startActivity(getIntent());


                                }


                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }

                            });
                        }
                      }
                    }
                }


                @Override
                public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError){

                }

            });


            mQuestionsList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);


}
```

Is there any smarter way to do it?

Extra question: Do I need to reload the entire activity or there is a way to reload only the RecyclerView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a straightforward approach to solving your problem. Your activity will no longer have to refresh itself, as that will be handled by your Adapter.
Structure your Database as such

```
rootNode
L ...category/questions...
L answeredQuestions
  L userId
    L randomQuestionId:true
L questionsForUser
  L userId
    L randomQuestionId:true
```

When your users answers a question :

```
add the questionId to answeredQuestions
remove the questionId from questionsForUser
call generateNewRandomQuestionForUser()
```

Replace your FirebaseRecyclerAdapter with a IndexedFirebaseRecyclerAdapter alike this:

```
new FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter<Question, QuestionHolder>(Question.class,
                                                   R.layout.question,
                                                   QuestionHolder.class,
                                                   keyRef, 
                                                   dataRef);
```

where keyRef and dataRef are both

```
Query keyRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("questionsForUser").child(userId);

Query DataRef  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Category").child(category_key).child("Questions");
```

and generateNewRandomQuestionForUser() is something like this:

```
   public static void generateNewRandomQuestionForUser(final String userId, final String category_key) {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("answeredQuestions").child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ArrayList<String> answeredQuestions = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (DataSnapshot questionId : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    answeredQuestions.add(questionId.getKey());
                }
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Category").child(category_key).child("Questions").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        ArrayList<String> availableQuestionKeys = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (DataSnapshot questionSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            availableQuestionKeys.add(questionSnapshot.getKey());
                        }

                        // Using answeredQuestions, availableQuestionKeys, you can user your own algorithm
                        // to select one at random that the user has not seen yet.
                        // Here you can also determine whether a user has seen all possible questions and update UI accordingly.
                        // Once you have your random question as keyOfRandomQuestion:

                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("questionsForUser").child(userId).child(keyOfRandomQuestion).setValue(true);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                });
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });
    }
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your help! When I try to replace FirebaseRecyclerAdapter with FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter it doesn't implement. I couldn't find any documentation about IndexedFirebaseRecyclerAdapter. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you have this library installed https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md